# How to add a 9patch image to a xml drawable

Tags: android

I have the following drawable which draw a rectangle. Can you please tell me how can I add a 9patch image as the background of this drawable?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> 
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" /> 
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a  drawable for that, but you can use a

```
<layer-list>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/mydrawable" />
  <item>
    <shape>...</shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I was using a drawable for that because I need to use that as the background of my text view and that drawable is used when the textview has focus.  For the layer-list solution, who can I set that so that android will use that only when the text view has focus?